# Split column names in R using a separator

Tags: r

I have a dataframe X with column names such as

```
1_abc,
2_fgy,
27_msl,
936_hhq,
3_hdv
```

I want to just keep the numbers as the column name (so instead of 1_abc, just 1). How do I go about removing it while keeping the rest of the data intact?
All column names have underscore as the separator between numeric and character variables. There are about 400 columns so I want to be able to code this without using specific column name

Comment: `gsub('\\D', '', c('1_abc', '2_fgy'))`

Answer (score 1):

You may use `sub` here for a base R option:

```r
names(df) <- sub("^(\\d+).*$", "\\1", names(df))
```

Another option might be:

```r
names(df) <- sub("_.*", "", names(df))
```

This would just strip off everything from the first underscore until the end of the column name.